# Help with Tailwind import

Tags: frontend

I'm working on a CraftCMS 4 + Vite + TailwindCSS + Docker Boilerplate. And it's almost working, except for the fact that I'm importing

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

but in my frontend there are no styles. There is something imported there, but I don't think it's the correct stuff. I'm very new to Tailwind (and Vite) so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Here you can see more details https://github.com/JorgeAnzola/craft-4-boilerplate/issues/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you just need to point Tailwind to the directories/files where it should scan for class names - in your case this might be simply `templates`. Add this in tailwind.config.js:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['templates/**/*.twig'],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Idk how you feel about it, but I could quite literally kiss you right now. Thanks mate!

Comment: ha ha, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing Craft / Vite / Docker / Tailwind boilerplate out there.

https://github.com/nystudio107/craft

You can have a look here.